# Ubuntu Multipass Cloud-init SSH Issue: Retaining 'ubuntu' User's SSH Key While Injecting My Own

Tags: ssh, cloud-init, multipass

I am trying to create a cloud-init configuration file to inject my own SSH keys into the "ubuntu" user for a Multipass instance. I have managed to successfully inject my SSH key when I create a new user for myself and set the SSH key for that user. However, the SSH key for the "ubuntu" user disappears in the process. How should I structure the YAML file so that the "ubuntu" user remains unchanged and I can still access the machine using SSH?

Here is my example cloud-init YAML file:

```
#cloud-config

users:
  - default
  - name: vmuser
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    ssh_authorized_keys:
    - ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza....

output:
  all: ">> /var/log/cloud-init-output.log"
```

Additionally, I have tried using the runcmd and echo commands to directly set the SSH key in the authorized_keys file, like so:

```
runcmd:
  - sudo echo "ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza..." >> ~/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

However, this does not work.

Any help or guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `~/home/ubuntu` = `/home/<user-the-command-is-run-as>/home/ubuntu`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ssh_authorized_keys` key should do what you need. The following example will set the key for your user along with the default `ubuntu` user:

```
#cloud-config

users:
  - default
  - name: vmuser
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    ssh_authorized_keys:
    - ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza....

output:
  all: ">> /var/log/cloud-init-output.log"

ssh_authorized_keys:
  - ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza....
```